# Divide a selected item of a list by another column in a DataFrame and chose top results

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have the following test DateFrame:

| tag | list | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| icecream | [['A',0.9],['B',0.6],['C',0.5],['D',0.3],['E',0.1]] | 5 |
| potato | [['U',0.8],['V',0.7],['W',0.4],['X',0.3],['Y',0.2]] | 5 |

Count is basically the number of lists in the DataFrame which I was able to get and add as a new column. I want to divide the score of the element in the list by the value in the 'Count' column. The result should be like this:

| tag | list | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| icecream | [['A',0.18],['B',0.12],['C',0.1],['D',0.06],['E',0.02]] | 5 |
| potato | [['U',0.16],['V',0.14],['W',0.08],['X',0.06],['Y',0.04]] | 5 |

How can I divide only the second element in the list with the count value.

I know if divide the list column by count column it wont work because one of the element is a string.

```
data = [['icecream', [['A', 0.9],['B', 0.6],['C',0.5],['D',0.3],['E',0.1]]], 
        ['potato', [['U', 0.8],['V', 0.7],['W',0.4],['X',0.3],['Y',0.2]]]]

test = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['tag', 'list'])
test['Count'] = test['list'].str.len().sort_values( ascending=[False])
test

test['list'].div(test['Count'])

gives an error which is expected: 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'
```

In next step, I want to only include the list whose value is in the first 10 percentile of the members. Let say, its like this:

| tag | list |
| --- | --- |
| icecream | [['A',0.18],['B',0.12],['C',0.1]] |
| potato | [['U',0.16],['V',0.14]] |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas cannot handle lists in a vectorial way. You have no choice here but to loop. The fastest will be a list comprehension:

```
test['list'] = [[[a, b/len(l)] for a,b in l]
                for l in test['list']]
```

Or, for in place modification a simple classical loop:

```
for l in test['list']:
    for x in l:
        x[1] /= len(l)
```

*NB. You do not need the "Count" column.*

Output:

```
        tag                                               list
0  icecream  [[A, 0.18], [B, 0.12], [C, 0.1], [D, 0.06], [E...
1    potato  [[U, 0.16], [V, 0.14], [W, 0.08], [X, 0.06], [...
```

Comment: Thanks, @mozway. That does get me what I need for part 1. Would you know how to loo into the second value which is a score in decimals and only keep value which is in 1 percentile?

Comment: How do you calculate the percentile? Do you mean you want values between 0.1 and 0.2?

Comment: I make a list of all the scores and pick the top percentile there. 
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5]) ; 
p = np.percentile(a, 50)

-- this will return 3 because 50th percentile is median and it is 3 here. Same way can I now get the 50th percentile for scores in the list and then only return the list element and score which is greater than or equal to let say 50th percentile. The values in the list are already in descending order in the list so we need not arrange

Comment: can I just filter the list column to include the data which has score greater than lest say 0.10? That way I have a threshold to test on and I dont consider element with a very small value.

Comment: Yes: `[[[a, b/len(l)] for a,b in l if b>=0.1] for l in test['list']]`

Comment: cool, yeah. I am able to assign it back to the same column